# Unable to resolve scalajs-sbt-plugin dependency

Tags: scala.js

I just tried to clone https://github.com/scala-js/scalajs-tutorial and I get this:

```
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-sbt-plugin;0.5.5 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs#scalajs-sbt-plugin;0.5.5
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs/scalajs-sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.5.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs/scalajs-sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/0.5.5/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\Joan\.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang.modules.scalajs\scalajs-sbt-plugin\scala_2.10\sbt_0.13\0.5.5\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scalajs/scalajs-sbt-plugin_2.10_0.13/0.5.5/scalajs-sbt-plugin-0.5.5.pom
```

I also opened an issue [here](https://github.com/scala-js/scalajs-tutorial/issues/3)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Qote from https://github.com/scala-js/scalajs-tutorial/issues/3:

> This resolver is supposed to be used by default by sbt >= 0.13.0.
>   And this has all been working fine for a year. Now suddenly people start having this issue :-s This doesn't make any sense.

Workaround: add explicitly the following resolver in `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url(
  "bintray-sbt-plugin-releases",
  url("https://dl.bintray.com/content/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases")
)(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```